# Android Color Picker Specific Colors

Tags: android

The user will be allowed to pick specific colors, around 10 different colors.In order to have a better user interface, the color picker should be on the layout page instead of using a dialog. I tried to use a number picker with the background as the color, but I can't. Preferably looks like the NumberPicker except with colors.

Answer (score 0):

In a recent application, I developed something similar based off of a project I found on Github. However, it is meant to be used as a ColorPreference not in a application Layout. This looks like what you want though and can be used as a Dialog or Fragment.

https://android-arsenal.com/tag/18

Comment: I would prefer using the application layout instead of a Dialog or Fragment.

Comment: You can put a Fragment in any Layout. I don't see how this is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a scrollable tab section at the bottom on the page where user can horizontally pick the color from it.

You can make use of [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)